# A leading decimal point can be confused with a dot

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, node-red

I try to get some info with weather underground with node red. I have made an HTTP request to have ten day hour by hour weather.

I need to extract one temp.
I use this:

```
var newMsg = { payload: msg.payload.hourly_forecast.0.temp.metric };
return newMsg;
```

The `msg.payload.hourly_forecast.0.temp.metric` works if I put it into debug console, but in my function, I have this error :

> A leading decimal point can be confused with a dot: '.0'

So i have try this :

```
var toto = 0;
var newMsg = { payload: msg.payload.hourly_forecast + '.' + toto + '.' + temp.metric };
return newMsg;
```

But not working and the error is

> ReferenceError: temp is not defined (line 2, col 74)

[image]

Comment: use `msg.payload.hourly_forecast["0.temp"].metric`

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'metric' of undefined" i have try msg.payload.hourly_forecast["0.temp.metric"] but message return nothing

Comment: can you please give us the output of `msg.payload.hourly_forecast `

Comment: the output is : https://ibb.co/ejaxge

Comment: Please don't post text as images. This causes a large number of problems.

Comment: @ThomasMantot Please use the built-in image upload tool when sharing images. That way, we can be sure the links stay valid and we're not redirected to unknown sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`msg.payload.hourly_forecast` is an array as shown by you here https://ibb.co/ejaxge

Please use `msg.payload.hourly_forecast[0].temp.metric`.

Read more about array here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

To address array elements in JavaScript you use the square bracket notation:

```
var newMsg = { payload: msg.payload.hourly_forecast[0].temp.metric };
return newMsg;
```

The Debug sidebar in Node-RED can also be used to identify the path to any message element. This is described in the documentation here: https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/messages#understanding-the-structure-of-a-message